# Invalid CFBundleSupportedPlatforms value iPhoneSimulator in (DJIWidget) FFmpeg.framework

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, app-store-connect, dji-sdk

I cannot upload my app which contains the DJI-SDK, DJIWidget(which contains FFMpeg) to Testflight after updating to Xcode 13. When I try I get:

> Invalid CFBundleSupportedPlatforms value. The
> CFBundleSupportedPlatforms key in the Info.plist file in
> “Payload/app.app/Frameworks/FFmpeg.framework” bundle contains an
> invalid value, [iPhoneSimulator]. Consider removing the
> CFBundleSupportedPlatforms key from the Info.plist file. If this
> bundle is part of a third-party framework, consider contacting the
> developer of the framework for an update to address this issue. With
> error code STATE_ERROR.VALIDATION_ERROR.90542 for id
> f2327257-ad48-4b60-8fc8-a518da5fbac8

```rb
# relevant pods
pod 'DJI-SDK-iOS', '~> 4.16'
pod 'DJIWidget', '~> 1.6.6'
```

However FFMpeg seems to be a binary file Framework attached to DJIWidget so I can't edit the Info.plist directly. Is there any way to workaround this or do I have to reach out to the DJI to actually make a change?

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to edit the Info.plist with a text editor and that is not possible when the plist file is embedded inside a bundled Framework.

I was able to edit the plist file with Xcode. Inside Frameworks folder - Right click FFMpeg - show in finder - open Info.plist with Xcode and set CFBundleSupportedPlatforms from iPhoneSimulator to iPhoneOS

Comment: I met the same issue like you. Lack of upgrades on DJI iOS SDK cause this issue. Anyway, thanks for your answer.